# How to view git errors in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have updated my git version on a Windows 10 machine running Jenkins. I did this to attempt to resolve a git LFS issue with new files that weren't downloading. After this update, my "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" is hanging when it does a git fetch and I notice that the local cache repository that it creates does not have any remote files downloaded to it (it stays at 25.7 KB across 19 files and 9 folders). This is what I see in the Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log:

```
Started by user admin
[Fri Jun 16 12:30:06 EDT 2023] Starting branch indexing...
Creating git repository in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\caches\git-13907a292e8cd0afde55a9f2fc947755
 > git init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\caches\git-13907a292e8cd0afde55a9f2fc947755 # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://github.com/[I have removed the rest of the URL]
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/[I have removed the rest of the URL] # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Git build credentials
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: [Fri Jun 16 12:40:06 EDT 2023] Could not update folder level actions from source 55deb54e-a4bc-4990-8406-9b7cf00937fd
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:352)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:344)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieveActions(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:581)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:746)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:591)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:276)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:978)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
[Fri Jun 16 12:40:06 EDT 2023] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 10 min
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of [My multibranch pipeline project]
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:352)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:344)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieveActions(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:581)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:746)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:591)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:276)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:978)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This error log doesn't seem to tell me much, other than the git fetch timed out. I've tried changing the credentials and I get the exact same problem.

Is there a way to get some more information or logs about what is happening here?

Comment: try to verify the credential, some time ago I had to create the credential set in the SCM again

Comment: I downgraded my git version and git LFS version to an older one and that seems to have resolved the problem I was having. I'm still not sure how to answer my original question, though.